# PoisonPill not killing the Akka actor system as intended

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to get a child actor in my Scala 2.11 app (that uses Akka) to send a `PoisonPill` to the top-level actor (`Master`) and shut down the entire JVM process.

I uploaded [this repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/akka-scala-troubleshooting) so you can reproduce what I'm seeing. Just clone it and run `./gradlew run`.

But essentially we have the `Driver`:

```
object Driver extends App {
  println("Starting upp the app...")

  lazy val cortex = ActorSystem("cortex")
  cortex.registerOnTermination {
    System.exit(0)
  }

  val master = cortex.actorOf(Props[Master], name = "Master")

  println("About to fire a StartUp message at Master...")
  master ! StartUp
  println("Fired! Actor system is spinning up...")
}
```

and then in the `Child`:

```
class Child extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case MakeItHappen =>
      println("Child will make it happen!")
      context.parent ! PoisonPill
  }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew run` I see the following output:

```
./gradlew run
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Starting upp the app...
About to fire a StartUp message at Master...
Fired! Actor system is spinning up...
Stage Director has received a command to start up the actor system!
Child will make it happen!
<==========---> 80% EXECUTING
> :run
```

However the JVM process never shuts down. I would have expected the `PoisonPill` to kill the `Master` (as well as `Child`), exit/shutdown the actor system, and then the `System.exit(0)` command (which I registered upon actor system termination) to kick in and exit the JVM process.

**Can anyone tell what's going on here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stopping the `Master`, but you're not shutting down the `ActorSystem`. Even though `Master` is a top-level actor (i.e., an actor created by `system.actorOf`), stopping it doesn't terminate the `ActorSystem` (note that `Master` itself has a [parent](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/general/supervision.html#the-top-level-supervisors), so it's not the "highest" actor in the actor hierarchy).

The normal way to terminate a `ActorSystem` is to call [`terminate`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.3/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#terminate():scala.concurrent.Future[akka.actor.Terminated]). If you want the entire system to shut down if the `Master` stops, then you could override the `Master`'s `postStop` hook and call `context.system.terminate()` there. Calling `system.terminate()` in an actor's lifecycle hook is risky, however. For example, if an exception is thrown in the actor, and the actor's supervision strategy stops it, you probably don't intend to shut down the entire system at that point. Such a design is not very resilient.

Check out this [pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/howto.html#shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) for shutting down an actor system "at the right time."

Comment: Thanks so much @chunjef (+1) - please see my updates to the repo, but essentially I just added `override def postStop() = context.system.terminate()` to `Master`. **It's now working!** However I do see the following warnings in the logs:

Comment: `[WARN] [08/02/2017 13:10:49.936] [Thread-0] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://cortex)] CoordinatedShutdown from JVM shutdown failed: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
[WARN] [08/02/2017 13:10:49.945] [cortex-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://cortex)] Coordinated shutdown phase [actor-system-terminate] timed out after 10000 milliseconds`

Comment: Any idea why I'm seeing those? I'd like to *not* see them if at all possible! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is going on here but shutting down the actor system inside actor's lifecycle hooks looks suspicious to me. More common approach is to shutdown the actor system from the outside or at least inside `receive`.

Comment: @smeeb: Updated with a link about how to shut down an actor system "at the right time."